# Implementing compile time warnings

Tags: java

Lets say I have three classes as follows

```
class A { //Master class.

  public int getNum() {
    return 1;
  }

}

class B extends A {
  @Override
  public int getNum() {
    return 2;
  }
}
class C extends A {
  @Override
  public int getNum() {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

Now if I neeed to create one more method (say getRandNum() on Class C),is there any annotation or something way to warn me while compiling that the method is only present in Class C but not in Class A(The master class) maybe some annotation like "ShowNotImplementedOnMasterClassWarning"?

Also,is there any way to add exception to the above mentioned rule? Maybe to create a method in Class C that need not be in Class A using some annotation like "SuppressNotImplementedOnMasterClassWarning"?

Edit: The problem is I have a very large codebase now and while writing the individual methods, the @Override annotation was ignored by the developers then and I couldn't find which are overridden methods and which are not!

So is there any way I can force all methods to have @Override annotation by default and perform @SuppressOverride for only the methods I dont need after checking?

Comment: If you use the @override annotation on a method that doesn't exist in the parent class, I believe you'll get a compiler error. Isn't that enough?

Comment: You can write your own compile-time annotations.

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Why is it important to know that a method in `C` is not overriding a method from `A`? When you have a variable of type `A` you can't call the new method from `C` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this in the first place?

If you have a method in class `C` that is not in `A`, you'll naturally get an error if you try to call it on an `A` object:

```
A a = new A();
a.getRandNum(); // error!
```

If you intend to put the method in every class and you want this warning because you are afraid that you might forget to add it to every class that needs it, don't worry. Just put the method in `A` and `B` and `C` will inherit it automatically.

Since this warning is not needed in the first place, you don't need anything to suppress it. Just write a normal method in `C` and it will only be in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

1. Require that all methods in class `C` have an `@Override` annotation.  If there is nothing to override you will get an error.
2. For the exceptions, omit the `@Override` annotation

Comment: The problem is I have a very large codebase now and while writing the individual methods, the Override annotation was ignored by the developers then and I couldn't find which are overridden methods and which are not! 

So is there any way I can force all methods to have Override annotation and perform SuppressOverride for the methods I dont need?